# How run Multiple c# class files

Tags: c#, botframework

I have these three class files which I am working on in the bot framework.But when I run my project in the bot emulator only the dialogs of the WelcomeDialog file runs and the other files don't
like if I say hi which is  from the WelcomeDialog file I get a corresponding  in the emulator but if say Search me something which is  from the Bing Search the emulator response with I am unable to understand sorry 
I don't know whether the problem is with the message controller file or what 
only single  cs file works at a time

```
    WelcomeDialog .cs


 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Search;
namespace MyFYP.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]   //As bot framework serilaizes and deserializes dialogs
    public class WelcomeDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {

            context.Wait(PerformActionAsync);     // calling PerformActionAsync
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        public async Task PerformActionAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {          //method
            var activity = await result as Activity;
            if (activity.Text.Equals("Hello") || activity.Text.Equals("Hi") || activity.Text.Equals("hi") || activity.Text.Equals("hii"))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Welcome to the Chatbot Portal of LMS");
            }
            else if (activity.Text.Equals("How are you"))
                await context.PostAsync("I am doing well AlhamdULLILAH what I can do for you");
            else if (activity.Text.Equals("what can you do") || activity.Text.Equals("What services you provide"))
                await context.PostAsync("i CAN OFFER A COUPLE OF SERVICES ");
            else await context.PostAsync("I am unable to understand you");
        }
    }



}
```

BingSearch.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
    using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Search;
    namespace MyFYP.Dialogs
    {
        [Serializable]   //As bot framework serilaizes and deserializes dialogs
        public class BingSearch : IDialog<object>
        {
            private string searchtype = string.Empty;
            private string query = string.Empty;
            private const string BING_KEY = "3b681ec3e2ed47f3930493d261a28e6d";
            private const string searchWeb = "Search Web";
            public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
            {

                context.Wait(MessageActionAsync);     // calling PerformActionAsync
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            private async Task MessageActionAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
            {          //method
                var activity = await result as Activity;
                if (activity.Text.Equals("Search me something") || activity.Text.Equals("i want some material"))
                {
                    PromptDialog.Choice(
                        context: context,
                        resume: ResumeAfterSearchTypeSelecting,
                        prompt: "Select searcht type you want to perform",
                        options: new List<string>
                        {
                            searchWeb
                        }
                        );
                }
            }
            private async Task ResumeAfterSearchTypeSelecting(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
            {
                searchtype = (await result) as string;
                PromptDialog.Text(
                        context: context,
                        resume: ResumeAfterEnteringQuery,
                        prompt: "Enter your query"
                        );
            }
            private async Task ResumeAfterEnteringQuery(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
            {
                query = (await result) as string;
                switch (searchtype)
                {
                    case searchWeb:
                        {
                            await BingSearchHelper.SearchWebAsync(context, BING_KEY, query);
                            break;
                        }

                }
                context.Wait(MessageActionAsync);
            }

        }
    }
```

BingSearchHelper.cs

```
    using System.Web;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
    using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Search.WebSearch;
    using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Search.WebSearch.Models;

    namespace MyFYP.Dialogs
    {
        public class BingSearchHelper 
        {
            public async static  Task SearchWebAsync(IDialogContext context,string key,string query)
            {
                IWebSearchClient client = new   WebSearchClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(key));
                var result = await client.Web.SearchAsync(query:query, count:3, safeSearch: SafeSearch.Strict);  
                if(result?.WebPages?.Value?.Count>0)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"Here is top 3 results for  {query} ");
                    foreach(var item  in result.WebPages.Value)
                    {
                        HeroCard card = new HeroCard
                        {
                            Title = item.Name,
                            Text = item.Snippet,
                            Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                            {
                        new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl,"Open Page",value:item.Url)
                            }

                        };
                        var message = context.MakeMessage();
                        message.Attachments.Add(card.ToAttachment());
                        await context.PostAsync(message);
                    }
                }
             }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In WelcomeDialog.cs you are calling context.Wait(PerformActionAsync ) which is executing the WelcomeDialog.PerformActionAsync function. Replace PerformActionAsync with BingSearchHelper.SearchWebAsync if you would like to run that function instead.

```
context.Wait(BingSearchHelper.SearchWebAsync);
```

To answer the bigger question of "How to run Multiple C# class files", you will typically do it one of two ways.

1. By creating an instance of that class and calling functions from that instance

   Animal dog = new Animal();

   dog.Sit();
2. Or if that function you want to call is *static* (meaning a class object doesn't need to be created like in the first example), you can simply call the class name followed by the function

   Animal.Sit();

Comment: I tried using context.Wait(BingSearchHelper.SearchWebAsync); but it caused an error in program and also I tried using WelcomeDialog. PerformActionAsync() but It didn't work